# Images wont display RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I dont know what should be the right title for this. I have this problem below.

I'm using this

```
$dataDir  = dirname(__FILE__).'/thumbnails/';

$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dataDir ); 
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);

            <?php foreach($it as $oneThing) { ?>        

            <?php       if (is_file($oneThing)) { ?>

            <?php       
                            $parent_info = $it->getFilename();

                            $temp = explode( '.', $parent_info );
                            $ext = array_pop( $temp );
                            $name = implode( '.', $temp );  

                            $filter1 = str_replace("thumbnail"," ",$name);                      
                            $filter2 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA]/','_', $filter1); 

                            $dirName = rtrim($filter2, '_');    
                            $dirName2 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA]/',' ', $dirName);    
                            $text_title = ucwords(strtolower($dirName2));
                            $text_category = ucwords(strtolower($rdi));

            ?>
                            <div class="portfolio <?php echo $rdi; ?>" data-cat="<?php echo $rdi; ?>">
                            <a href="single-gallery.php?imgcat=<?php echo $rdi; ?>&dirname=<?php echo $dirName; ?>">
                                <div class="portfolio-wrapper">             
                                    <img src="<?php echo $oneThing; ?>" alt="" />
                                    <div class="label">
                                        <div class="label-text">
                                            <a class="text-title"><?php echo $text_title;  ?></a>
                                            <span class="text-category"><?php echo $text_category; ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="label-bg"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>    
                            </div>              

            <?php       }    ?>

                <?php }  ?>
```

to get images on directories and subdirectories. But i can't get the image to show.

I setup this in a wordpress site.

this is the link that will generate.

```
<img src="/home/content/10/11383810/html/alteverswp/wp-content/themes/canvas/thumbnails/custom/cr_indian_wells/cr_indian_wellsthumbnail(1).jpg" alt="">
```

What might be the  correct way to make the images display correctly.

Comment: _other code here_ Display the code.

Comment: @RahilWazir i added now the full code.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the absolute path rather than the relative path. Here is a working example:

```
function directoryScan($dir, $onlyfiles = false, $fullpath = false) {
    if (isset($dir) && is_readable($dir)) {
        $dlist = Array();
        $dir = realpath($dir);
        if ($onlyfiles) {
            $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
        } else {
            $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        }

        foreach($objects as $entry => $object){ 
            if (!$fullpath) {
                $entry = str_replace($dir, '', $entry);
            }

            $dlist[] = $entry;
        }

        return $dlist;
    }
}

// return contents of ‘Folder’ – Relative Paths and Only Files.
$result = directoryScan('folder', false, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @mister but i can't get the code to work using this. What should be the right way?

Comment: @JanBantolinay try this: `<img src="<?php echo ltrim(str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $oneThing), '/'); ?>" alt="" />`

Comment: @JanBantolinay I copy and pasted your code and tested it locally. The change noted above works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use $it->getType();  for getting the extention like 'jpg'.

And think once more about the 'absolute path' 'relative path'.
eg:
URL         `http://test/image.jpg`

ABSOLUTE    `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\image.jpg`

RELATIVE    `\test\image.jpg`  (when do scandir in \htdocs)

Go into a Browser and look, with Firebug, from where the Images are loaded.

Look at the part before `/home/..` there is the error.

Then you have to change your script, 
that the right URL_PATH is generated.

And what the biggest errros in your script is:
The use of $it->getFilename();  when you have to use  $oneThing->getFilename();

Look here(First example): 
http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php

Understand the way 'recursiveiteratoriterator' 
and 'splfileobject' work , before going on.

Hope that help!

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to achieve turn it into a relative path. But i'm not sure how could i do that. I tried modifying the code as said above but its still the same path i get.

Comment: Keep in Mind that the relative path must fit with the current url or use the meta BASE Tag to override the BASE_URL, but that can break css,js loading and other relative links.

Comment: Lets say you are in www.foo.com/test/index.php  then www.foo.com/test/home/content/10/11383810/html/alteverswp/wp-content/themes/canvas/thumbnails/custom/cr_indian_wells/cr_indian_wellsthumbnail(1).jpg will be the url for the image

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $oneThing; ?>" alt="" />` you take it as it is and dont  turn it into a relative path see comment from @JanBantolinay